# Which edit on this question should be used?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

[What is the Biblical argument that homosexual attraction is sinful by itself?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/35233/3961)

I've had a bit of an edit war with another user. Would the community please weigh in on which edit is more appropriate.

All the edits are in the revisions. There are applicable comments on the post too.

Comment: @FMS I don't think your @ call will work if he hasn't previously commented in this meta question thread.

Comment: @Jas3.1 Comments are disabled. Perhaps he may be notified by the Mods.

Comment: @Jas3.1 We commented plenty and linked to this meta before it was locked. He'll see it. If he wants to stop by he will.

Comment: I believe someone should reach out to him. His input is required to resolve this discussion. Mods have e-mailed me before, they could do the same or utilize such other methods.

Answer (score 6):

I favor the first revision.

And the reason is as follows:

- The question, prior to editing starts with an a priori assumption that the act of SSA is sinful. Any attempt to alter this changes the meaning of the question significantly.
- None of the later revisions provide meaningful changes while adhering to the spirit of the original question.

Based on point 2 (and nothing else), I've reverted to the first edit and locked it for a day. If a meaningful revision is developed in this meta post I will be happy to revert the lock early.

Comment: Thank you for locking it. In the future I can flag for that right?

Comment: @fredsbend yes, though the preference is meta discussion, so you're doing it right. If I'm going to content lock it should be because of pending meta discussion

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest

- Making the question a What is the Biblical basis for ... question (both the title *and* question body)
- Changing fundamentalism (which isn't clearly defined) to protestantism, or perhaps just removing the scoping entirely. Saying that the OP has "encountered Christians from a more fundamentalist background" is fine, but I think it would be better to broaden out the scope for answers. (Partly because I'd like to answer it ;))

Comment: Problem is, this is no longer a uniformly "Protestant" view. Evangelical maybe? I think Fundamentalist is clear enough, but perhaps something generic like "those who hold this view" would suffice.

Comment: Yeah it's not something all protestants will believe, but asking for the protestants who do is better than the fundamentalists who do. I don't think any scoping is really needed though... it can just ask for the basis from those who believe it.

Comment: @curiousdannii So you agree the body and title do not match?

Comment: @FMS Not really. They're basically the same. The body is just more specific, which I think should be removed.

Comment: *They're basically the same'* is NOT they are the same. And they are, my edit is just as valid as fredsbend's and better because title and body match.

Comment: @FMS Well if it helps, I'm suggesting that you're both wrong! :)

Comment: @curiousdannii I can't be if I am repeating what the body says!

Answer (score 0):

[I support revision number six.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/revisions/35233/6)

Comment: Could you elaborate on *why*?

Comment: @waxeagle I thought FMS would be amenable to it. In my opinion it does not change the question in any significant way, but it seems like it does to him. I would also be content with revision 1, which you've now rolled back to.

Comment: I'll agree with this - it seems like it might not be a bad thing to specify in so many words (what I thought was probably obvious) that those referred to in the question body do in fact use Scripture to support their position.